# How do I add conditional statements to test for a specific value in dynamic where clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure into which I pass a number of variables and I create a dynamic where clause using the "AND (@var IS NULL OR table.field = @var)" and it works great... EXCEPT

One of the variables (@statusLevel) can be either 1-9 or 10.  When the value passed in is 10, I want to return ONLY those projects that have a statusLevel = 10. When the value passed in is between 1 & 9, I want to return all of the projects between that value (let's say '5') and less than 10.

I've got each part working perfectly independently but I'm lost on how to get them to work together.

```
AND ((@statusLevelID IS NULL OR project.statusLevelID >= @statusLevelID) AND (@statusLevelID IS NULL OR project.statusLevelID < 10))
AND (@statusLevelID IS NULL OR project.statusLevelID = 10)
```

Using an "OR" just gives me ALL of the projects.

```
AND ((@statusLevelID IS NULL OR project.statusLevelID >= @statusLevelID) AND (@statusLevelID IS NULL OR project.statusLevelID < 10)
OR (@statusLevelID IS NULL OR project.statusLevelID = 10))
```

I was thinking a CASE statement might work here but I'm not exactly sure how to implement that.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are generating dynamic sql, then you shouldn't be referring to your null variables AT ALL in the where clause after generation. That approach negates the point of using dynamic sql. Erland discusses this in great detail [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one boolean expression connected by `OR`s:

```
AND ( (@statusLevelID IS NULL) OR
      (@statusLevelID = project.statusLevelID) OR
      (@statusLevelID <> 10 AND project.statusLevelID >= @statusLevelID AND project.statusLevelID < 10)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the condition like so:

```
AND (
    @statusLevelID IS NULL
    OR
    project.statusLevelID BETWEEN @statusLevelID AND IIF(@statusLevelID = 10, 10, 9)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an answer as well but I need to understand the IIF a bit more before I use it in case I need to modify it again later.

Comment: `IIF(cond, val1, val2)` is just a syntactic sugar for `CASE WHEN cond THEN val1 ELSE val2 END`